# Is it possible to forbid downloading flash from the server?

Tags: flash

I have page with code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="170">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="movie" value="./Flash/1385125408.swf">
<embed width="170" src="./Flash/1385125408.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
```

I would like that user can see animation on page(that they can sse animation only on page) but can not download animation from server.

Is it possible to forbid downloading flash from the server?

Comment: Have a look at streaming

Answer (score 0):

The flash file *is* the animation. You can prevent people from downloading it just by removing it from the server, but your animation will disappear too.